# The required anti-forgery cookie “__RequestVerificationToken” is not present

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csrf, antiforgerytoken

As I have deployed my newly created Asp.Net MVC web application to the server, I am facing the subject error, upon submitting a sign-up form. It is working fine in my local environment.

In my controller's action method, I have set the attribute to validate the token as shown below:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    ////
}
```

And in my view, I have set as:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    }
 ////
)
```

One more thing is that I have enabled SSL on my project properties. I have also added `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>` in my web.config file.

[image]

While inspecting, I can see the hidden element `<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="blaa blaa>"`, but i cannot see any cookie present there.

After hours of troubleshooting, I am still unable to find a solution to this problem. I am always getting error `The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.`

How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself has find the answer to this question. In my case, as I have set SSL to true, I need to have a security certificate. So, I purchased and configured the certificate on my hosted site and the error has gone.

Comment: Can you please add more details to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

For me it had to do with a limit in asp.net in the request body size.
I suspected it when this error ocurred only for files more than 4MB.
Adding a bigger size than the default of 4MB in the web.config resolved the error:

```html
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.1" maxRequestLength="10096" />
```

ASP.NET Request Limits: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx
IIS Request Limits: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits